# How to stop alert box press enter loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user presses enter on the document, I show an alert box with `alert()`.

The default behaviour the browser (Chrome 27 on Mac OS X 10.8.4) has is when you press enter when focused on the alert box, it will close it. That will trigger the enter on the document, showing the alert box again. You can see how it can loop.

Note that when I use my mouse to click OK in the alert box, the loop does not happen.

**How can I prevent this looping?**

An example (the real way I use this is a lot more complicated):

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (keyCode == 13) {
        alert('Hello world!');
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: That's not how it works. pressing enter to close the alert doesn't trigger a key event on the document. (at least not in chrome 28 win64) http://jsfiddle.net/Y8pW3/ probably because the document is locked and can't process any commands while the alert is open.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 27 on Mac OS X. Your demo behaves exactly as I've described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can delegate the `keydown` event and use `stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling up to the document when it is triggered on the alert dialog, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/KNyzc/

```
$(document).on( "keydown", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (keyCode == 13) {
        alert('Hello world!');
    }
});
```

( actually, you don't need to use `stopPropagation` at all. Just use the keydown event. )